# Control's .className not working Angular2

Tags: angular

Anybody have any idea why I can see the `valid` and `pristine` here, but `className` comes back blank?

```
<label for="codeInput" class="control-label"> Fund Code:</label>
<input #code="ngModel" id="codeInput" class="form-control" name="codeC" required [(ngModel)]="fund.code">
Info: ({{code.className}} ) {{code.valid}},  {{code.pristine}}<br>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a console.log of `code` ?

Comment: What `className` value are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the local variable `code` is just grabbing a reference to the `ngModel` directive and not the `elementRef` of the input. `ngModel` has access to the `valid` and `pristine` properties but does not have access to `className`. You can specify another local variable to get a reference to the `input`, which does have the `className` property, and a reference to the `ngModel` like so:

```
<label for="codeInput" class="control-label"> Fund Code:</label>
<input #code="ngModel" #codeInput id="codeInput" class="form-control" name="codeC" required [(ngModel)]="fund.code">
Info: ({{codeInput.className}} ) {{code.valid}},  {{code.pristine}}<br>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFOhoaj3I8la8O21490J)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="code" class="control-label"> Fund Code:</label>
<input #code="ngModel" id="code" class="form-control" name="code" required     [(ngModel)]="fund.code">
Info: ({{code.className}} ) {{code.valid}},  {{code.pristine}}<br>
```

Try this it will work.

In angular to when working with form you need to maintain same name for **name="code"** ,**[(ngModel)]="fund.code"** ,**#code="ngModel"**,**id="code"** and in **for="code"** for label.

if it didn't work please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the template variable `#code` refers to the `ngModel` instance created on the input element, which is an extension of the [AbstractControlDirective](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControlDirective-class.html). As you can see in the documentation this has a `valid` and `pristine` property.

There is obviously no `className` property on this class. Perhaps adding another template variable to the input will do the trick (although I fail to see what you want to achieve with this :)):

```
<input #input #code="ngModel" class="control" name="code" required [(ngModel)]="fund.code">
Info: ({{input.className}} ) {{code.valid}},  {{code.pristine}}
```

Comment: It was just an exercise from a course - i was only wondering why it din't work.

Comment: @kpollock ah, that makes sense!